# How to plot two regions such that both are visible and also highlight the overlap?

Tags: plotting, regions, inequalities

I try to plot the following inequalities `f[x,y,z]<=1` and `g[x,y,z]<=1` in a single plot such that both the regions are visible and also the intersection is highlighted. I tried the RegionPlot3D but it only shows the region which is common to them.

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = x + y + z;
g[x_, y_, z_] = x^2 + y^2 + z^2;

RegionPlot3D[f[x, y, z] <= 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
RegionPlot3D[g[x, y, z] <= 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: One of those regions is completely within the other, tho; is something like `RegionPlot3D[{x + y + z <= 1, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[1/3]]` what you had in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_, z_] = x + y + z;
g[x_, y_, z_] = x^2 + y^2 + z^2;
```

Since the region `f[x, y, z] <= 1` is completely contained in the region `g[x, y, z] <= 1`, the intersection is just the smaller region. You cannot distinguish the smaller region from the intersection.

```
RegionPlot3D[{f[x, y, z] <= 1, g[x, y, z] <= 1, 
  f[x, y, z] <= 1 && g[x, y, z] <= 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5], Opacity[0.5], Automatic},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

However, if the neither region is completely contained by the other

```
RegionPlot3D[{f[x, y, z] <= 1, g[x, y, z] <= 1/2, 
  f[x, y, z] <= 1 && g[x, y, z] <= 1/2}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5], Opacity[0.5], Automatic},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bob, it worked fine when I copied it first time, but now it is showing "{x+y+z<=1,x^2+y^2+z^2<=1,x+y+z<=1&&x^2+y^2+z^2<=1} must be a Boolean \
function"......don't really understand what's wrong here!

Comment: Quit Mathematica and restart it. Copy, paste, and evaluate the code above.

Comment: Still showing the same message :-(

Comment: What Mathematica version are you using?

Comment: 11.3, on Win 10

Comment: I can't help since I don't have access to that version.